# Adding toolbar to taskbar doesn't render properly in Win 7 (or any other version of Windows, afaik)

Tags: windows, taskbar, desktop-toolbar

I've raised this for Win7 because that's what I'm using now, but this has been happening for as long as I've been using Windows. Which is a long time.

First, right click the taskbar and ensure that "Lock the taskbar" is selected.

Now, if I right-click on the taskbar, I can select Toolbars -> Links to add a Links toolbar. This gets added to the right hand side of the toolbar. It looks something like this:

[image]

If I now right click the toolbar and untick "Lock the taskbar", then I get a drag bar to resize or move the toolbar. It looks like this:

[image]

I can drag this bar to make the toolbar bigger. I can't make it smaller at this point because it is currently the smallest it can be. After dragging it around for a bit return it to where it was, i.e. the smallest it can be.

Now right-click the toolbar and tick "Lock the taskbar" again. Now, it looks like this:

[image]

The edge of the first icon is now poking out. I don't want to see this - it looks untidy. and the point of the toolbar is to have a list I can expand when I want to, and is small and unobtrusive when I don't. I have tried everything I can think of to get rid of this but I just can't.

This happens as soon as you try to move the toolbar, and since I almost always want to move a toolbar once I've created it, this is extremely annoying.

This issue has existed in Windows for as long as I can remember. Does anyone know how I can get round it?

---

**UPDATE:** I am now using Windows 10, and the problem still exists.

Comment: Its indeed hard to get by. What I usually attempt, is to rename the label to something short, like L, then lock the taskbar, then rename it back to Links.

Comment: @LPChip How do I rename it? I feel like I've done that in previous versions of windows, but I can't work out how to do it now.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I think I did: hide label, then show label, but in windows 10, that option is not allowed when the taskbar is locked. Honestly, I don't know. I have managed in the past in windows 7, but it is so long ago, I don't remember.

Comment: Something like DisplayFusion should provide additional features for the modification of the taskbar.

Comment: Looks like a pretty powerful product, but I can't see anything on their help pages that mention Toolbar customisation. And the full version is not free.